# 6 pin B50K potentiometer: DIY alternative?

Tags: potentiometer, diy

I have a 6-pin B50K potentiometer used for the Bass/Treble control of a desktop speakers set.
This pot is broken and getting this piece is costly to get (price, time - mainly from China).

I don't need to tweak the Bass/Treble at the hardware level ( never had to ), is there a way to bypass this with a basic resistor? Which one, pls?

thanks

Comment: Most likely it is possible to bypass, but without further info it will not be possibe to say how exactly it would be possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 6-pin pot is dual channel. This means you have two pots in one enclosure. The top level 3-pins are the first pot and the bottom level 3-pins are the second pot. You can choose to replace them with 4 regular 25K resistors. Replacing the 50K variable value with the center value of 25K. This gives you the 'center' value of the original setup.

Comment: Hello @Rens 
Thank for your swift response, it makes so much sense that I feel ashamed. :/